# Create a radio group in pdflib with perl

Tags: perl, pdf, sign, radio-group, pdflib

I am trying to create a radio group with pdflib.
This code works:

```
my $optlist = "required buttonstyle=circle bordercolor={gray 0.8} backgroundcolor={white}";
        $p->create_field($llx, $lly, $llx + $width, $lly + $height,"colors.standard", "radiobutton", $optlist);

        $p->create_field($llx + 115, $lly, $llx + $width + 115, $lly + $height,"colors.yellow", "radiobutton", $optlist);

        $p->create_field($llx + 230, $lly, $llx + $width + 230, $lly + $height,"colors.blue", "radiobutton", $optlist);
```

When I try to make it as required by [Adobe Sign](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/sign.html), it gives me errors with either path error or the name does not show up right.

{{Color_es_:signer1:radio(Red)}}

{{Color_es_:signer1:radio(Blue)}}

{{Color_es_:signer1:radio(Green)}}

If we have to use a different perl module we could.

Comment: What module do you use? I cannot see any method `create_field()` in [`PDFLib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDFLib)

Comment: @HåkonHægland https://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-9.2.0-API-reference.pdf

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I cannot parse "make it as required by Adobe sign it".

Comment: @melpomene  Adobe sign is a service by Adobe that lets you have people sign documents electronically. The require the radio boxes to be labeled like thisColor_es_:signer1:radio(Green)

Comment: @user3308713 I tried to download PDFlib-9.2.0-Linux-x86-perl from https://www.pdflib.com/binaries/PDFlib/920/PDFlib-9.2.0-Linux-x86-perl.tar.gz but when I run the sample script `hello.pl` I get `./perl528/pdflib_pl.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`.. I am not sure what is going on. Do I have to run an installation script first?

Comment: @HåkonHægland That's the 32-bit library. Are you on a 32-bit system?

Comment: @user3308713 Where is that documented?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with pdflib but with Adobe Sign documentation.

to them 
{{Color_es_:signer1:radio(Red)}}

means to put the group names as Color_es_:signer1:radio and the value as Red.

Once we figured that out pdflib worked fine. Hopes this helps someone else.